# Supporting Dynamic Type in React Native (iOS)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Does anyone know how to implement Support For Dynamic Type in React Native?

Ideally, we would like to listen for when someone has changed the size of the system font, and perform some type of callback.

Or even better, prevent Font Scaling from being implemented at all on some components.

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, turns out you can apply:

`allowFontScaling={false}`

To prevent this.

**This worked for me:**

```js
<Text allowFontScaling={false}>Do not want font to scale</Text>
```

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem globally, set allowFontScaling in defaultProps of your root component like so:

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false; // Disallow dynamic type on iOS
}
```

Comment: I put this in my app constructor and I am getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false')`

Comment: Try without the `defaultProps`. ie. `Text.allowFontScaling = false;`. Looks like it is a recent change to RN (see: https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/issues/1313)

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you should not prevent font scaling as you will be deliberating making your app less accessible. Some users find it difficult to read content due to sensory difficulties or hardware limitations like small screens.

Comment: This is the only correct answer.  People scale fonts because they can't read otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

Late here but needed this to work for me

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {}
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false
```