# Since React Native uses pixels or percentages for units, how do we handle accessibility of larger text for input

Tags: react-native, expo, accessibility

Since React Native [uses only pixels or percentages for units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248400/what-dimension-units-are-used-in-react-native), how do we handle accessibility of larger text?

I know I can [disable font scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573718/react-native-ios-enabling-larger-text-form-accessibility-messed-up-everythin), but that is what I specifically do not want to do.

I am asking specifically for `TextInput` since there are other parts of the screen which won't change even if you scale up like the bottom nav bar.  Because say we set a widget for time input on the browser we can say `5em` to limit it to 5 character sizes regardless of the size of the text.

One way I can think of is to use `* 16` in place of `em` but that does not work when you scale up the font since 16 is fixed.

Also I am looking for something that works in Expo.  [AccessibilityInfo](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v42.0.0/react-native/accessibilityinfo/) does not appear to provide the size and I can't find any information on accessing the value of [Dynamic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046443/supporting-dynamic-type-in-react-native-ios)

My crazy idea at the moment is to have a transparent `Text` that I has an `onLayout` and I obtain the size of the component and set it in a context that all my custom `TextInput` will use as a [measurement that has a size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128201/how-can-i-measure-text-in-react-native-using-the-expo-framework) based on number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

[react-native-elements](https://reactnativeelements.com/) is utilizing a helper function called `normalize` for font scaling which is implemented as follows.

```js
import { moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
function normalize(number, factor = 0.25) {
    return moderateScale(number, factor);
}
export default normalize
```

I'm currently using [react-native-size-matters](https://github.com/nirsky/react-native-size-matters) on developing UIs for multiple devices along with above font scaling by [react-native-elements](https://reactnativeelements.com/). Works fine in almost all the time.

Check out the [react-native-size-matters](https://github.com/nirsky/react-native-size-matters) repo is you have doubts on the implementation. Author has a [good article written](https://medium.com/soluto-engineering/size-matters-5aeeb462900a) on explaining his approach as well.

Comment: Not really correct because this talks about sizing based on the screen.  HOWEVER, it did lead me to the right answer.

Comment: Yes I checked the repo, and looked for the call for getFontScale but I didn't see it so I presume they're not using that value.

Answer (score 0):

[`PixelRatio.getFontScale()`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v42.0.0/react-native/pixelratio/#getfontscale) allows you to get the font scale that adjusts its number based on the user's choice of dynamic type.

The number you can use as a multiplier on the widths to increase or decrease depending on the font size if a dynamic font size is used.

One thing to note though, changing the size does not trigger a re-render unlike `useColorScheme()` since there's no context provided that has this information.